# Which class should I use to write binary data to a buffer (say a List of bytes)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I would like to encode data into a binary format in a buffer which I will later either write to a file or transfer over a socket. What C# class or classes would be best to use to create a `List<byte>` containing the binary data.

I will be storing integers, single byte character strings (i.e., ASCII), floating point numbers and other data in this buffer in a custom encoded format (for the strings) and regular binary numeric layout for the ints and floating point types.

`BinaryWriter` looks like it has the methods I need, but it has to manage a growing buffer for me that I want to produce a `List<byte>` result from when I am done encoding.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx), writing to a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).  If you need more than the available memory, you can easily switch to a [temporary file](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/tempfiles.html) stream.

```
using (var myStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var myWriter = new BinaryWriter(myStream)) {
        // write here
    }
    using (var myReader = new BinaryReader(myStream)) {
        // read here
    }

    // put the bytes into an array...
    var myBuffer = myStream.ToArray();

    // if you *really* want a List<Byte> (you probably don't- see my comment)
    var myBytesList = myStream.ToArray().ToList();
}
```

Comment: You're missing the conversion to List<byte> which was the final result I asked for, but I gave you the checkmark nevertheless.

Comment: That was intentional.  You *probably* don't want a `List<byte>`, because that would imply that you are altering the buffer's contents.  That is almost never done, and in fact all of the BCL APIs that take a buffer do so using a `byte[]`, not a `List<byte>`.  That said, I've edited the answer for completeness.

Comment: Fair enough! I've given you a +1 on top of the accept for the explanation in the above comment.

Answer (score 2):

BinaryWriter writes to a stream.  Give it a MemoryStream, and when you want your `List<byte>`, use `new List<byte>(stream.GetBuffer())`.